# adding ng-model to my checkbox flickers the modal in the angular screen

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngcloak

how to avoid flicker of a modal box upon clicking on a chekckbox inside that modal

```
<time-checkbox  name="show" id="show" class="form-checkbox" >Show</time-checkbox>
```

I tried ng-cloak, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it can happen that Bootstrap and AngularJS combinations are not the most fortunate ones. Here's an interesting article on this topic: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

I'd suggest you either use a directive to add Bootstrap to you AngularJS project (which is what the guy in the article above suggests too): https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ or, if your project allows it, simply opt for the more easy to use and elegant Angular Material solutions.
Hope this will help!